# fopen & cURL on php ubuntu web server

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, fopen

Whether I'm trying to create a file, or use file_get_contents on a external url I just can't seem to get fopen (or curl) code to work. I have checked phpinfo and allow_url_fopen, allow_url_include & curl are all set to on and even looked at the php5/apache2/php.ini and they are all set to on.
But not matter what I do no php code works. Below are some examples (that work on wamp/localhost but not when moved to live web server)

create a html file in folder (works on windows localhost/wamp server)

```
if (!file_exists('media/folder')) {
 mkdir('media/folder', 0755, true);
 }
 $config_file = 'media/folder/config.html';
 $config_file_handle = fopen($config_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$config_file); //implicitly creates file

 $config_file = 'media/folder/config.html';
 $config_file_handle = fopen($config_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$config_file);
 $config_data = 'add to my file content'.PHP_EOL.'

';
fwrite($config_file_handle, $config_data);
```

Does not work on live server. Quite frustrating as this needs to work and have tried many curl options but fail as well.

Below is another php code snippet that works locally but not live.

```
<?php

//works locally if external url used
//works locally if local file used
//Does not work live server if external url used
//Does work live server if local server url used
$string = file_get_contents('my url');
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);

foreach ($json_a as $person_name) {

//Person Name
echo $person_name['PersonName'];

}
?>
```

Cant really achieve what is have set out to do if I can't get this to work.

Any Help appreciated

Comment: And the `mkdir()` will only succeed if the web server _already_ has write permission to the parent directory of the one you're trying to create. That would mean your web server has to have write permission to the current directory where this code is running - that is a little dangerous.  If the `mkdir()` is what fails, you'll see warnings about that immediately.

Comment: I get Warning: fopen(config.html): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/my url/public_html/write.php on line 7 Cannot open file: config.html when trying to write file to root folder

Comment: That would indicate the web server user doesn't have write access to the config.html file.

Comment: Does `media/folder` already exist in this case? I would assume it does because otherwise `mkdir()` would have errored too.  The Apache web server user is typically named `httpd, apache`, or `www-data` (assuming you're using apache)  (addendum -you said this is Ubuntu, so `www-data` will be the username)

Comment: Yes Apache and while in ftp, the owner group is my user name | www-data which was set in a terminal command

Comment: ok set it to owner group to www-data | www-data and run the script and file was written. But is this leaving me open to an "outsider" writing files?

Comment: If only the `media/folder` directory is writable by www-data, that isn't too serious a problem. You might also consider setting only its group to `www-data` and making it group writable rather than www-data owned.  You probably should not have _this_ directory where the code executes writable by www-data though - only locations where writes will actually occur.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everything working as it should, saving to media/folder. Execute script is in another folder.

Answer (score 1):

An extremely common error, you may need to allow the user www-data to access your desired files. Simply right click on the file or folder you want click properties, go to the permissions tab and set www-data to the owner.

Comment: Thanks dude but dont have a right click option of a GUI to use as just on terminal. But yes I did use command sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path to www folder and the php script works (file create/write)

Comment: if this was the answer can you click the tick next to it, thanks.